# What do we do with these 5 questions about Software Center from today?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Snapcraft is having some firewall issues today, resulting in issues with the Snap Store crashing. As a result, we now have *five* questions asking about crashing Software app, all from today.

[Ubuntu Software is closing when I select application to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412986/ubuntu-software-is-closing-when-i-select-application-to-install)

[Ubuntu 22.04 software installer crashes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412960/ubuntu-22-04-software-installer-crashes)

[Could not install any app via Software in Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412939/could-not-install-any-app-via-software-in-ubuntu-22-04)

[Can't launch ubuntu-software / QSnapStore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412900/cant-launch-ubuntu-software-qsnapstore)

['Software' keeps crashing after updating to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412896/software-keeps-crashing-after-updating-to-22-04/1412992#1412992)

What do we do about these kinds of situations/this specific case? Can 4 of them be closed as duplicates of one of them (I put comments by most and answers to one, but it's ridiculous to keep all of them here)?

Comment: Which of those is the oldest?  I'll dupe-close the others as a dupe of the original and post a canonical answer that "Currently, the Snapcraft team/sites are having a large number of firewall problems, and as such there are errors being returned.  This is entirely on the Snapcraft backend admins to fix their issue, and there's nothing we can do about it for now."

Comment: looks like https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412900/cant-launch-ubuntu-software-qsnapstore is the oldest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the questions on this have been dupe-closed as duplicates of ['Software' keeps crashing after updating to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412896/software-keeps-crashing-after-updating-to-22-04/1413019#1412896)

I have posted an answer on that question which points to the Snapcraft intermittent outages being reported by them, and protected the post as it's a "current event" issue.

Any more posts that are created between now and a firm resolution of the problem by Snapcraft should be dupe-closed / dupe-flagged as the aforementioned post.

Answer (score 7):

> What do we do about these kinds of situations/this specific case?

On the broader side of things, it's exactly the same as any other question, just a little more urgent. **Deal with them.** Get them answered, and closed, and dealt with as quickly as possible.

The quicker we have a body of material that actually deals with the problem, or let's people know what's going on, the quicker Google will start returning those things when people search for the errors they see. Even if you vote to close (dupe), leaving *extra* comments can help people while it's being closed, even duplicate answer in a complex situation. The system isn't going to explode.

Everything we do here —not just surge situations— isn't just to help one person, it's to help the next ten people with the same problem. It's to deduplicate the effort at both ends of the problem.

In a surge, the tail, the time our answers will help is short but we have to act really quickly to avoid lots of people having to hunt for the answer, ask duplicate questions, and leave us with even more work to answer them.

---

In this case, I'd be tempted to butcher the title on the canonical answer thread so it's clear this is a "June 2022" problem that's being described, but I'd leave that until after it's resolved maybe? Who knows.